# Should I encrypt the IV and Key in AES-256-CBC before entering into the database?

Tags: php, cryptography, aes

I have started using AES-256-cbc for encryption of sensitive data in my PHP powered website.

Now, personal messages between users must be encrypted before storing them into the databases, I am using MySQL for that.

I have used        openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32) for generating a random key and        openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length(AES_256_CBC))
for generating an IV which I will be appending to the encrypted result string.

But when I saw the actual strings of key and iv, I found out they were not plain text. Therefore storing them into my db could be a bit problematic and also carrying that data wont be as easy. Now, should I do something like hashing the iv and they key with md5 or sha256? Or maybe bcrypt? And should I base64 encode the entire encrypted string as well?

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to ask yourself: What is the point of encrypting your data?

You want to protect your data at rest in the DB, thus anybody obtaining a DB dump won't get any insights to the messages. However, in your app you will need to display those messages.

So if you store the key together with your encrypted data in the DB, that's rather pointless. Which key would you use anyway to encrypt the key? Would you store it in the DB as well?

So you have to ensure that anybody who gains access to your DB won't be able to see the AES key. You need to store the key somewhere on the app side. Read the encrypted data from the DB and encrypt it on your app host in memory. You may use a configuration file, a keyring, whatsoever.

That's the basic use case. However, since you are encrypting messages which might get large and thus encrypting large volumes of data, it might indeed be a good idea to create a new key for each message. Then you would use one master key to encrypt the message encryption keys before storing them along with the message in the DB. The previous paragraph applies likewise.

The IV is not sensitive at all, you can just store it as it is.

Regarding your encoding problem: since the bytes of an IV and the key can have all possible values, a printable string is not a proper representation use some sorts of binary storage in your DB.